# SQL query for retrieve rank list

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called 'scoreboard' of a game with following contents

```
+-----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
| Team_name | Level    | Status | completed_time      |
+-----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
| sample1   |        1 | yes    | 2011-09-11 15:15:44 |
| sample2   |        1 | yes    | 2011-09-11 15:48:13 |
| sample2   |        2 | yes    | 2011-09-11 15:50:13 |
| sample2   |        3 | yes    | 2011-09-11 15:52:13 |
| sample1   |        2 | yes    | 2011-09-11 15:16:52 |
| sample1   |        3 | yes    | 2011-09-11 15:31:06 |
| sample1   |        4 | yes    | 2011-09-11 15:31:47 |
| sample1   |        5 | no     | 2011-09-11 15:31:47 |
| sample2   |        4 | no     | 2011-09-11 15:52:13 |
| sample4   |        1 | yes    | 2011-09-12 17:11:51 |
| sample4   |        2 | yes    | 2011-09-12 17:12:18 |
| sample4   |        3 | yes    | 2011-09-12 17:16:53 |
| sample4   |        4 | yes    | 2011-09-13 22:58:24 |
| sample4   |        5 | yes    | 2011-09-14 03:03:21 |
| sc102     |        1 | yes    | 2011-09-14 01:42:20 |
| sc102     |        2 | no     | 2011-09-14 01:42:20 |
| sample4   |        6 | yes    | 2011-09-14 03:08:20 |
| sample4   |        7 | no     | 2011-09-14 03:08:20 |
| Javad     |        1 | yes    | 2011-09-14 21:07:05 |
| Javad     |        2 | yes    | 2011-09-14 21:08:47 |
| Javad     |        3 | yes    | 2011-09-14 21:18:40 |
| Javad     |        4 | yes    | 2011-09-14 21:25:12 |
| Javad     |        5 | yes    | 2011-09-14 21:34:25 |
| Javad     |        6 | yes    | 2011-09-14 21:41:33 |
| Javad     |        7 | yes    | 2011-09-14 21:47:31 |
| Javad     |        8 | yes    | 2011-09-14 21:48:15 |
| Javad     |        9 | yes    | 2011-09-14 21:48:25 |
| Javad     |       10 | yes    | 2011-09-14 21:49:07 |
| SCAV527   |        1 | yes    | 2011-12-05 21:15:30 |
| SCAV527   |        2 | yes    | 2011-12-05 21:20:30 |
| SCAV527   |        3 | yes    | 2011-12-05 21:20:46 |
| SCAV527   |        4 | no     | 2011-12-05 21:20:46 |
+-----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

I need to prepare rank list of game based on level solved by the team and its completed_time. If more than one team solved a level, the priority goes to the team who solved first based on completed_time. And the row with status 'no' should omited while preparing rank list.

Output of the query should have fields such as team_name, level, completed_time.

Can you please help me to write a SQL query for rank list? I am using MySQL as back end.

Output of the query should be like this.

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| Rank      | Team_name | Level    | completed_time      |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| 1         | Javad     |       10 | 2011-09-14 21:49:07 |
| 2         | sample4   |        6 | 2011-09-14 03:08:20 |
| 3         | sample1   |        4 | 2011-09-11 15:31:47 |
| 4         | SCAV527   |        3 | 2011-09-10 21:20:46 |
| 5         | sample2   |        3 | 2011-09-11 15:52:13 |
| 6         | sc102     |        1 | 2011-09-14 01:42:20 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 as rank, r.*
FROM (
    SELECT team_name, MAX(level) as level, MAX(completed_time) as completed_time
    FROM results
    WHERE `status` = 'yes'
    GROUP BY team_name
    ORDER BY 2 DESC) as r, (SELECT @rank:=0) as init
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a view using this query?

Comment: @user1101518, I am not sure since I have not dealt with views yet.

Comment: Its working almost 90%. But the problem is that, its not sorting based on completed_time. That is, its not sorting based on who is completed first. Can you help for this?

Comment: @javad_shareef, could you be more specific what works incorrectly? Are there any conditionas that the solution doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Someting like this might help:

```
SELECT v1.Team_name, v1.Level , COUNT(v2.Level) AS Rank
FROM scoreboard v1
JOIN scoreboard v2 ON v1.Level  < v2.Level  OR (v1.Level =v2.Level  and v1.Team_name = v2.Team_name)
WHERE v1.status = "yes"
GROUP BY v1.Team_name, v1.Level 
ORDER BY v1.Level  DESC, v1.Team_name DESC;
```

Comment: I tried this. Its not telling about the completed_time. And the output am getting is not like as above.